2Hire Webhook URL Not Working in Express.js After Conversion from Fastify
I recently converted a Fastify application handling 2Hire webhooks to Express.js. However, the webhook URL isn't triggering as I expected.
2Hire webhooks Subscription API Doc: https://developer.2hire.io/reference/subscribe-1
2Hire webhooks Receiving signals Doc: https://developer.2hire.io/docs/receiving-signals
Error
{
    "message": {
        "code": "CHALLENGE_ERROR",
        "errorId": "2c31cx-x-x-x-x82034a925",
        "details": {
            "cause": "CHALLENGE_FAILED"
        }
    }
}

Despite setting up the raw body correctly and configuring the endpoint, the webhook does not trigger when tested.
Can anyone help identify what might be going wrong or what I may have missed in the conversion?
Below is the core part of my implementation:

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config();
const app = express();
const SECRET = process.env.SECRET;
const PORT = 8080;

const signalNames = new Set(["online", "position", "distance_covered", "autonomy_percentage", "autonomy_meters", "*"]);

function isSignal(signal) {
    return signalNames.has(signal);
}

function validateTopic(topic) {
    const parts = topic.split(":");
    return parts.length === 4 && parts[0] === "vehicle" && parts[2] === "generic" && isSignal(parts[3]);
}

function generateSignature(message, secret) {
    const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret);
    hmac.update(message, 'utf8');
    return `sha256=${hmac.digest('hex')}`;
}

app.use(bodyParser.json({
    verify: (req, res, buf) => {
        req.rawBody = buf.toString();
    }
}));

app.get('/listener', (req, res) => {
    const { 'hub.mode': mode, 'hub.topic': topic, 'hub.challenge': challenge } = req.query;
    if (!validateTopic(topic) || mode !== 'subscribe') {
        res.status(400).send('Validation error');
    } else {
        res.send(challenge);
    }
});

app.post('/listener', (req, res) => {
    const signature = req.headers['x-hub-signature'];
    const computedSignature = generateSignature(req.rawBody, SECRET);
    if (!validateTopic(req.body.topic) || signature !== computedSignature) {
        res.status(401).send('Invalid signature or topic');
    } else {
        console.log("Webhook Received: ", req.body);
        res.send('Webhook received');
    }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});




converting the error responses to JSON format then it might work
app.get('/listener', (req, res) => {
    const { 'hub.mode': mode, 'hub.topic': topic, 'hub.challenge': challenge } = req.query;
    if (!validateTopic(topic) || mode !== 'subscribe') {
        res.status(400).json({ message: "Validation error" }); // Change response to JSON format
    } else {
        res.status(200).send(challenge);
    }
});

app.post('/listener', (req, res) => {
    const signature = req.headers['x-hub-signature'];
    const computedSignature = generateSignature(req.rawBody, SECRET);
    if (!validateTopic(req.body.topic) || signature !== computedSignature) {
        res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid signature or topic" }); // Change response to JSON format
    } else {
        console.log("Webhook Received: ", req.body);
        res.status(200).send('Webhook received');
    }
});


Nope, this we have tried already. We're also talking with 2Hire developer, and they said to not use res.status(401).json({}), but we have to use this way
server.get('/listener', async (req, res) => {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain').send(req.query["hub.challenge"])
})

Even we did, but not working.
Do you have any other way to implement?
